# Why ActualWidth don't changed after hiding TextBlock in Icon1(UserControl) in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

How to get the actualWidth after hide the TextBlock in Icon1 ?
Why both Width1 and Width2 are Same after hide the Label? I want the ActualWidth of the Icon1 after Hide the TextBlock(Label).
I need to do some action after changing the visibility based on ActualWidth!!

I also have one more question . i.e., Before hiding the visibility of label ,is there any way to determine the actualWidth(What will be the Width of Icon1 by Hiding label) of Icon1 ??

My Complete [Project Link.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1w2l0pr0hoa4K-jOWBvb_c6Rhptooia4N?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why both Width1 and Width2 are Same after hide the Label?

If you print Width2 with debug writeline, you will find it will update when next  `SizeChanged`, the problem is you get Width2 value before UI update, it will return previous value. please set a task delay before `width2`, you will get updated value 46.

```
await Task.Delay(100);
double width2 = icon1.ActualWidth;
```

> Before hiding the visibility of label ,is there any way to determine the actualWidth.

As you mentioned above you could call ActualWidth property to return Width value.

**Update**

```
bool isResize; //set it as true after Label hidden.
private void Icon1_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (isResize)
    {
        var newSize = e.NewSize;
       // do your action here.
    }

}
```

Comment: Task.Delay was not the perfect solution for this. It will Reduce the Performance !!

Comment: well, please listen icon1 SizeChanged change event, and you will get the new size immediately, please refer above update part .